# How to check using JavaScript that custom application is installed in the system?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, custom-url, custom-url-protocol

I have installed a custom application in my system and I want to check..Is application is installed or registered in registry?

I want to perform some action based on that status but I am unable to detect or read registry from Browser. I have gone through sooo many question/solutions but they did not work for me.

If you can help me to achieve my wish...that would be really helpful for me.

When I trigger my custom URI then following Log prints in console based on
If Application installed then `Launched external handler for 'myApp://dgsda'.`
If Not Installed then `Not allowed to launch 'myApp://dgsda' because a user gesture is required.`

But I am unable to catch these logs.

I am sharing few approaches that I have tried.

`Custom URI : myapp://anything`

```
 var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      window.location = newUri
    }, 1000)
window.location = uri;
```

With Above approach Timeout is always executing

```
 var iframe = document.querySelector('#hiddenIframeUriHandler')
  
    if (!iframe) {
      iframe = _createHiddenIframe(document.body, 'about:blank')
    }
  
    try {
      iframe.contentWindow.location.href = uri;
      successCb()
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.name === 'NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL') {
        failCb()
      }
    }
```

Please do let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: There is a requirement for user interaction to play a sound in a web page. There might be the same thing for application launch. There is also no event for these trigger, programmatically, like you said, simply logs in the console.